# AMDGPU liveCD issue

Tags: system-installation, amd-graphics, live-cd, amdgpu

i recently tried to install Ubuntu on my new laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 320 15abr) which has the new AMD Radeon 530 graphic card. I've tried to install different versions (16.04, 17.04 and the daily build of the 17.10) but the problem is always the same: in liveCD or in the installation process, the mouse freezes after 20/30 seconds and i can't use it anymore, But i can still use the system with the shortcuts. I've tried also with the nomodeset flag, disabling fast boot and secure boot in the BIOS and with the legacy mode enabled but nothing. Once the system is installed, i can't login because it hangs at the login screen.
I think the problem is that my graphic card is too new for amdgpu driver. Is there a way to install Ubuntu or do i need to wait new drivers?

Thank you for your patience.

Comment: this sounds more like a mouse driver issue than a graphics issue

Comment: I don't think it's a graphics driver matter, because this error would not happen with nomodeset flog. You could try a non-GUI install (ubuntu-server, for example), after that, install a GUI like ubuntu-desktop. If even in Ubuntu Server this install hangs, you have another hardware issue.